# Error with installing ROS indigo on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install Ros indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I'm following the link http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu. However when ever I try to do the line

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It gibes me the error

```
N: Ignoring file 'ros' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
```

I've tried to redo everthing multiple times, and my friend was able to do this without any problems.

What is the solution?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263621/error-with-installing-ros-indigo-on-ubuntu-14.04/) by [Wheeleral](https://answers.ros.org/users/30723/wheeleral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> It gibes me the error

> ```
> N: Ignoring file 'ros' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
> ```

which I feel in this case is pretty clear: you have a file which has just a name - `ros` - but without any file extension. `apt` doesn't know what sort of file that is, so it decides to ignore it.

From the wiki page you linked:

[image: image description]

Did you perhaps not copy the entire line? That would result in a file named `ros` to be created, instead of `ros-latest.list`.

Try adding the extension `.list` to the file and see whether that improves things. I suspect it will (provided that the file contains what it is supposed to).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0